# JQuery tabs system

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp, tabs

Wrote this script and it all seems ok to me but for some reason jquery doesnt want to work. Been trying to get this to work for ages with no luck. If you wouldnt mind could you skim over it for me. I apologise if i am missing something simple but my eyes are glazed now lol.

heres the html & php

```
<ul class="tabs">
     <li class=""><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#contact">Contact <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></a></li>
 </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
  <div id="about" class="tab_content">
         <h3>About <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['description'];?></p>
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="tab_content">
         <h3>Contact <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h3>
            <h4>Email <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['email_address'];?></p>
            <h4>Phone <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['phone'];?></p>
            <h4>Fax <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['fax'];?></p>
            <h4>Write to <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['address_line_1'];?>,<br /><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['address_line_2'];?>,<br /><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['city'];?>,<br /><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['county'];?>,<br /><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['postcode'];?></p>
  </div> 
    </div>
```

Heres the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 //Default Action
 $(".tab_content").hide();  
 $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();  
 $(".tab_content:first").show(); 

 //On Click Event
 $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); 
  $(this).addClass("active"); 
  $(".tab_content").hide();  
  var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");  
  $(activeTab).fadeIn(); 
  return false;
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Sorry cant give you all a link but its on local machine.

Thanks folks

Jamie

Comment: works fine on 1.4.4: http://jsfiddle.net/2JQvu/

Comment: yeh i think it should work fine and all my other jquery things are working i really cant understand why it isnt. Thanks for testing:)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the offictal jQuery UI documentation, in particular the [tabs page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). I think your markup has some errors, this is how I would do this:

```
<div id="tabs_container">
<ul>
    <li class=""><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#contact">Contact <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></a></li>
</ul>
  <div id="about" class="tab_content">
         <h3>About <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['description'];?></p>
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="tab_content">
         <h3>Contact <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h3>
            <h4>Email <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['email_address'];?></p>
            <h4>Phone <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['phone'];?></p>
            <h4>Fax <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['fax'];?></p>
            <h4>Write to <?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['company'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['address_line_1'];?>,<br /><?php echo  $retailers['Retailer']['address_line_2'];?>,<br /><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['city'];?>,<br /><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['county'];?>,<br /><?php echo $retailers['Retailer']['postcode'];?></p>
  </div>
```

You need a div which contains all the tab divs AND the  list with the various links, you missed this in your code. Then in your jQuery code you're missing a call to .tabs() which effectively creates the tabs. Here is how you would do this assuming you where using the previous markup I posted:

```
$('#tabs_container').tabs()
```

Comment: see i wasnt too keen on the Theme roller thing with the Jquery UI tabs thats why i tried to do it this way. If I do it like you said would that mean creat a function tabs. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your first question a bit. Anyway jQuery UI has a built-in tabs feature and you could use that to create the tabs if your solution isn't working still. You don't have to create a .tabs() function because it is built-in into jQuery UI!

Comment: like i said i dont want to use that because i dont like the way you style it with the Theme roller would rather use my own jquery do you have any tips that i could get this to work :)

Comment: Well, in this case I don't really know since the code you posted seems to be working fine for me... what's the problem you're experiencing?